# Unable to Unserialize value error in Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, unserialize, conditions-serialized, serializer

I have had this problem for some time, on the admin custom grid. can anyone tell me any solution to this ?
Check This Below Screenshot For Reference: 
https://i.imgur.com/5XvLhIh.png

Comment: can you check the db to see how the conditions_serialized and actions_serialized fields look like?

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding, make sure to take a backup of your database and the affected tables, or work on a staging/development environment to avoid any potential data loss.

```
SELECT * FROM salesrule WHERE your_serialized_field LIKE '%s: %';
```

Replace your_serialized_field with the specific column that contains the serialized data.

Remove Invalid Entries.